# Any way to disable notifications' sound when screen is on? On Stock Android

Tags: notifications, audio, customization, android-10

Is there any reasonable way to disable all android notification sounds (only) when your screen is on, but keeping them working when screen is off?

By 'stock' I mean a Pixel (3) device.

Rationale: If my screen is on, *it means I'm actually actively **looking at it***. I turned it on, and if I'm not looking at it anymore, I'd lock (turn off) it again, or the auto turn-off timer will do that for me, preferably in the shortest amount of time possible, saving battery.

The nature of notifications, as the name imply is to **notify**. If I'm looking at the screen, I don't need an annoying audio cue as well to notify me of anything: I will **see** the visual cue.

**I've already been notified.**

The default behaviour seems rather dumb and unthoughtful to me, and it's beyond me why they wouldn't give such an alternative option.

I've encountered this option on a custom ROM I've used on my OnePlus 3T before, and it was a blessing.

As such, is there a way to fix this (IMHO, terrible design flaw)?

Comment: I'm currently testing to see if the app Dingless will work. I should mention however that unfortunately for some reason it's not compatible with my OnePlus 3T running stock OnePlus Pie.

Comment: Would this suffice if the default notification sound is changed to none when the screen is on, then back to your default when the screen is off? Automation apps such as MacroDroid and Tasker can do this easily.

Comment: @Firelord Yes, off the top of my head I believe the practical results of that method would fulfill all the requirements I was aiming for, and I couldn't think of any meaningful side effects. I'll take a look into that.

Comment: Can't upvote this more and weird that so few people are annoyed by this terrible flaw. I'm  going to give a shot to Automateit app.

Comment: For what it's worth: After reading the comments here, I've installed MacroDroid, and created the following auto routine: "On screen unlocked -> silence the notifications and disable vibrations -> only if I've not enabled Do Not Disturb". "On screen off -> do the reverse with the same 'only if' condition". 1. I didn't use "On screen on", because that also silences the phone alarm. 2. I added the 'only if' condition, so that I have a way to silence the phone and keep it silenced after I turn the screen off. I.e. I can do it by enabling the Do Not Disturb mode.

Answer (score 0):

So I've tried the app dingless, and it totally works, even on my Galaxy A52s (Android 12). You can even customize it to not vibrate at all, driving mode and a lot more.